# Uncaught TypeError on a Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unfortunately, I bought a Wordpress template without a support and now I try to debug it myself.

One of the bugs that I cannot solve is a recursive console error about JQuery. In specific, it fires whenever I scroll with the mouse.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

The Javascript code of the error is the following:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = jQuery(document).height();

        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {

            if( aArray[i].indexOf("#") != -1) {

                var theID = aArray[i].substr(aArray[i].indexOf("#"));
                if (theID.length) {
                    var divPos = jQuery(theID).offset().top; // HERE IS THE ERROR, get the offset of the div from the top of page
                    var divHeight = jQuery(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
                    if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                        if(jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
                        }
                        else if(jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").addClass("nav-active");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                        }
                        else if(jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }   
        }

        if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
            if (!jQuery("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
                var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
                jQuery("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                jQuery("nav li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
            }
        }
    });
```

The error fires on the line `var divPos = jQuery(theID).offset().top;`. I added manually the `if statement` to check if there is a `theID` variable and then execute the code, but still the error fires on the browser console.

Comment: can you `console.log(theID)` for a quick glance at what it is?

Comment: It was the anchor of the menu items. However, the solution of vlarsson made the error stop raising. Probably my `if statement` wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script can't find the object in the DOM, it will break. Try to check if it exists or not.

```
if (theID.length) {
        // Check if you find the object in the DOM
        if(jQuery(theID).length > 0) {
                    var divPos = jQuery(theID).offset().top; // HERE IS THE ERROR, get the offset of the div from the top of page
                    var divHeight = jQuery(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
                    if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                        if(jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
                        }
                        else if(jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").addClass("nav-active");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                        }
                        else if(jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").length) {
                            jQuery("a[href='" + aArray[i] + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                        }   
                    }
                }
           }
```

Comment: Didn't the first `if statement` I added does the same thing as yours?

Comment: It only checks if the string theID is set. If it can't find jQuery(theID); offset() won't work. So you can remove that and only use my check :)